# Can Gparted make a jump move of a partition?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, gparted, gdisk, move

There is a similar question: [GParted moving partition from beginning of disk to the end of a disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/489600/gparted-moving-partition-from-beginning-of-disk-to-the-end-of-a-disk)

I know I can move a partition left / right if there is a free space to the left or to the right of a partition. But can I move a partition to another free space, that is laying somewhere at another area?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes

As of gparted 1.1.0, there is no such function as “jump move” for partition. But you can do a copy paste of a partition with right click menu and then you can delete original partition.
However, you should be aware that this new partition may/will have some differences from original one. Check the following list and edit parameters as necessary if you want to make fully identical copy, like if you just moved a partition.

**Start and end sectors** will be apparently different. Probably it it may have some side effects for booting in legacy mode.

**Partition number** - this is that number which is displayed near a disk name, for example /dev/sda**3** or /dev/nvme0n1p**3**. 3 is a number of a partition. In some cases it is important.

- You cannot change it with gparted interface. You may use gdisk or cgdisk for this purpose.
- Partition numbers may be assigned not sequently. For example, they may follow in such order: sda1, sda3, sda2.
- In gdisk partitions are sorted by partition number, but in cgdisk they are sorted by position on disk.
- To change partition number in gdisk, type x, then t, then enter number of another partition you wish to exchange.

**Partition unique GUID** - it is a partition id in the gpt. You cannot see it in gparted, but you can see it in cgdisk. If you want your new partition to have identical GUID from the original partition, remember it before deleting original partition. Then you could use gdisk: enter x (extra functionality), then c (change partition guid), then number of a new partition, then enter guid number, then press enter and w to write changes.

**Partition GUID code** - it is marking a partition type. You cannot see it in gparted (?). You can change it in cgdisk/gdisk (the short numbers stands for full guid numbers).

**Partition name** - this is a name of a partition in gpt. It is not a file system label. You can set it in Gparted in the Name column.

**Attribute flags** - some flags

Note that moving partitions in case of msdos partition table may have other limitations, especially with extended partition. And you use fdisk instead of gdisk.