Move unallocated space into extended partition to expand primary partition
Is there any way in Ubuntu to extend the /dev/sda2 partition according to the screenshot?
I can only extend LVM, GParted doesn't allow moving unallocated space behind the /dev/sda2 partition. Thank you in advance.


It would not be easy to combine non-contiguous space. One might combine sda5 and the unused space. Before making any change, make a disk image, lest a change make a mess of it.

gparted should let you slide the other partitions over. Or you could make a new partition in the unallocated space and copy the data over. https://superuser.com/a/489617/673426
